# call_user_func_array not working for me

Tags: php

I have to call a method, when I would have something like:

```
class foo {
    function bar($arg, $arg2) {
        echo __METHOD__, " got $arg and $arg2\n";
    }
}
```

It's work, but I have a library class, which contains many classes.

For example to call the class foo and the method bar I call following:

```
$core->FOO->bar(1, 2);
```

When I now try

```
call_user_func_array(array($core, "FOO", "bar"), array(1, 2));

I get following error: 

Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, 
array must have exactly two members
```

Any ideas how I can solve my problem?

EDIT:

Thank you guys for your help, I solved it with your help.
I call

```
all_user_func_array(array($core->FOO,"bar"), array(1, 2));
```

Comment: did you read the error message? "... parameter 1 to be a valid callback". You're not passing in a valid callback. You're passing in an array with three members...

Comment: How do you get `array($core, "FOO", "bar"),` as the callback to the `bar` method of `foo`? Why is `FOO` capitalised, when the classname is lower-case?

Comment: Use array($core->FOO, 'bar') as your first arg.

Comment: Use `array($core, "bar")` as your callback.... assuming that `$core` is an instance of your `foo` class

Comment: @MarcB the array syntax is fine. You should likely RTFM http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php ... call_user_func_array(array($foo, "bar"), array("three", "four"));

Comment: my problem is i have a json entry in my database, which says when for example you call the command: !hello in a chat you have to call $core->HELLO->hello_world() it looks like ["HELLO","hello_world"] and with array_unshift i put $core in front of the array, after my json_decode. So I dont know before which class I have to load from my library. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

It should look like this:

```
$foo = new foo;
call_user_func_array(array($foo, "bar"), array("arg1", "arg2"));
```

Comment: Not constructive as he is trying to access an auto-loaded class via the magic method __get

Comment: @LuckyBurger - where does OP mention any autoloader? Not that it makes any difference whether it's autoloaded or not

Comment: "I have a library class, which contains many classes." It's a similar pattern to the way Code-Igniter works. @prodigitalson has the correct answer.

Comment: @LuckyBurger and when do I miss the magic method form the OP question? ;-) I think you are overinterpretating